# MPAndroidChart - Multiple lines for chart.setNoDataText

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I'm using the MPAndroidChart library which has a string written on the chart if no data is available yet.

If the string is too long, it seems to just overflow to both sides of the screen so I'm wondering if it's possible to make that text use multiple lines, because neither `\n`, `<p>`, nor `<br>` work.

The method to set that text is `chart.setNoDataText(String)` where chart is a LineChart view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is impossible, if you take a look at source of the library, here how it draws text

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mData == null) {    
            boolean hasText = !TextUtils.isEmpty(mNoDataText);    
            if (hasText) {
                MPPointF c = getCenter();
                canvas.drawText(mNoDataText, c.x, c.y, mInfoPaint);
            }    
            return;
        }

        if (!mOffsetsCalculated) {

            calculateOffsets();
            mOffsetsCalculated = true;
        }
    }
```

Here main line is

```
canvas.drawText(mNoDataText, c.x, c.y, mInfoPaint);
```

Library draws text `mNoDataText` as **single line**, starting from c.x, c.y.
`canvas.drawText()` doesn't know how to handle newlines.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. A little sad that it's not possible but definitely not the end of the world.